# Bisection Search to find a min payment that causes an infinite loop

Tags: python, bisection, edx

This is my first post, so apologies if it isn't the best!

I'm taking an online class (Edx) and attempting to write a bisection search that finds the minimum payment to clear a credit card balance. You are given the balance and annualInterestRate. My code runs into an infinite loop and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

### Supplied test conditions -- should produce Lowest Payment: 29157.09

```
balance = 320000
annualInterestRate = 0.2

monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate / 12.0
lower = balance / 12.0
upper = (balance * ((1 + monthlyInterestRate) ** 12.0)) / 12.0
guess = (upper + lower) / 2.0
valid = True
month = 0

def calculate(month, balance, guess, monthlyInterestRate):
    while month < 12:
        unpaidBalance = balance - guess
        balance = unpaidBalance + (monthlyInterestRate * unpaidBalance)
        month += 1
    return balance

while valid == True:
    if calculate(month, balance, guess, monthlyInterestRate) == 0:
        print('Min payment is: ', str(round(guess,2)))
        valid = False
    elif calculate(month, balance, guess, monthlyInterestRate) > 0:
        lower = guess
    elif calculate(month, balance, guess, monthlyInterestRate) < 0:
        upper = guess
    else:
        print('Invalid Input')
    guess = (upper + lower) / 2.0
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: It looks like the value never equals 0, hence the infinite loop. Stepping through your code now for a better understanding.

Comment: Suggestion: follow your code using ipdb https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipdb. Infinite loops tend to be easy to discover using a debugger.

Comment: It's looping because of rounding and comparisons to precise values. Floating point arithmetic seldom produces exact values. Suggest you consider using the [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#module-decimal) module to do the calculations.

Comment: Yes, what @martineau said.

Balance: `29158.73165236825`
Guess: `29156.95544617364`
UnPaid: `1.776206194608676`
Balance: `1.8058096311854872`
Month: `12`.

That's the end result of your script's values.

Comment: One alternative to using the `decimal` module would be to do the calculations with integers (so dollars would have to be converted to whole cents). When calculations occur that produce floating point results (as this problem requires)—just remember to round it or them to the nearest cent. This will require an extra step but I don't think it's a very expensive thing to perform.

Comment: Hey everyone -- thanks for the help! I didn't get the notices of the responses and was checking the page out of hope.

So, essentially I set up a condition (to equal 0) that could never occur. So I need to either round the calculations or create an epilson value that the difference can be less than (condition < epilson instead of ==0).

Thanks again everyone who responded. I'll check out the debugger and the decimal module!